# Run Shortcut.link File target File

Tags: c#

How can I run the target path of a shortcut.link

I already try to run this one to `process.start` but isn't working,
Please help me about this.

> e.g. >> C:\TeklaStructures\19.0\nt\bin\TeklaStructures.exe -I
>   "Y:\ICON\HERRICK LIC.19.O ICON\MODELER\usimp_bypass_login.ini" -i
>   "Y:\INI\HERRICK_V19.0.ini"

```
process.start(C:\TeklaStructures\19.0\nt\bin\TeklaStructures.exe -I "Y:\ICON\HERRICK LIC.19.O ICON\MODELER\usimp_bypass_login.ini" -i "Y:\INI\HERRICK_V19.0.ini");
```

> ERROR: An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

UPDATE: the target path contains 1 exe and 2 script file, if i dissect target path, it is possible to convert it to array, open it 1 by 1 then it still will works fine?

example:

```
arr[0] = C:\TeklaStructures\19.0\nt\bin\TeklaStructures.exe
arr[1] = Y:\ICON\HERRICK LIC.19.O ICON\MODELER\usimp_bypass_login.ini
arr[2] = Y:\INI\HERRICK_V19.0.ini
```

then Ill open it each of them

```
process.start("C:\TeklaStructures\19.0\nt\bin\TeklaStructures.exe");
process.start("Y:\ICON\HERRICK LIC.19.O ICON\MODELER\usimp_bypass_login.ini");
process.start("Y:\INI\HERRICK_V19.0.ini");
```

[image: example]

Comment: Please give some details on *isn't working*. Is there any exceptions? Can you post the code of yours?

Comment: @Irshad id already post my code etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried as following;

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\myShortcut.lnk";
proc.Start();
```

replace `c:\myShortcut.lnk` with the full path of the **shortcut**. Not the target path etc..

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect problem in your `process.start`, arguments are not well formed.

Below code should work for you.

```
Process.Start(@"C:\TeklaStructures\19.0\nt\bin\TeklaStructures.exe",@"-I ""Y:\ICON\HERRICK LIC.19.O ICON\MODELER\usimp_bypass_login.ini"" -i ""Y:\INI\HERRICK_V19.0.ini""");
```

or

```
var p = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        Arguments =@"/c ""C:\TeklaStructures\19.0\nt\bin\TeklaStructures.exe"" -I ""Y:\ICON\HERRICK LIC.19.O ICON\MODELER\usimp_bypass_login.ini"" -i ""Y:\INI\HERRICK_V19.0.ini""",
        FileName = "cmd"
    }
};
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
```